# Executing a command as a nologin user

Tags: linux, user-permissions, su, login

I've recently set up my server so that my suPHP 'virtual' users can't be logged into by using [**this article**](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-shell-restricting-access.html)

My issue now is that before when I ran a `rake` command for my Ruby on Rails application running on the server, I used `su` to go into `www-data` and execute the command from there - obviously I can't do that anymore because of the nologin.

So as a root user, how can I execute commands as other user's, even if they are nologin?

Comment: One way is to launch a shell for that user (explicitly specifying the shell): `sudo -u www-data bash` execute your command(s) and logout

Comment: @cyberx86 Your solution works a treat, could you submit it as an answer for me?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

One way is to launch a shell for that user (explicitly specifying the shell):

```
sudo -u www-data bash
```

This will launch a (bash) shell as the specified user. You can then execute your command(s) and logout (to return to your previous shell)

Answer (score 56):

As root you can use `su -s /bin/sh $user` — the `-s` option overrides the configured shell for the user.

Comment: This always seems to error for me.

Comment: Works great for me, never had a prob. When running scripts with bash syntax needs /bin/bash rather than /bin/sh

Comment: This answer is a life saver in situations where you don't have sudo - such as when working in kubernetes pods