# How to run command as user who has /usr/sbin/nologin as Shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, su, login

All I need to do is to run a specific script as a particular user who does have the `nologin/false` shell indicated in `/etc/passwd`.

I would run the script as root and this should run as another user.
Running:

```
~# su -c "/bin/touch /tmp/test" testuser
```

would work, but I need a valid shell for the testuser.
I know I can disable the password with `passwd -d testuser` and leave the shell to `/bin/bash` this way would secure a little bit but I need to have `nologin/false` shell.

Basically what I need is what `crontab` does when we set jobs to be running as a particular user, regardless this one has `nologin/false` shell.

p.s I found this thread [Executing a command as a nologin user](https://serverfault.com/questions/333321/executing-a-command-as-a-nologin-user), but I have no idea how to `concatenate` the command `su -s /bin/sh $user` to the script I need to run.

Answer (score 153):

You can use the -s switch to su to run a particular shell

```
su -s /bin/bash -c '/path/to/your/script' testuser
```

(Prepend `sudo` to the above if `testuser` is a passwordless user.)

Comment: What if su is `root:root -rwsr-x---` ?

Comment: What if the user doesn't have a password?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai That is left as an exercise for the student.

Comment: @Wesley Found out that you need to be root to run that command for passwordless user.

Comment: @lain, If the user is supposed to not have a shell, the process related to the command should not be a child of a bash process. Thus, you should also use exec to replace the shell with the script. And if you like to make the script a child of init, you just use &, as an example `su -s /bin/bash -c 'exec /path/to/your/script &' test `

Comment: Since I have spent last 20 minutes working out how to achieve the same result using `runuser`, I'd like to point out that `su -s SHELL` parameter renders runuser command pretty much useless :) Thanks Jan!

Comment: @CMCDragonkai use sudo: `sudo su -s ...`

Comment: If called from root, `runuser` is preferable. It is compatible whith `su`.

Comment: Anyone know the mac way to do this? `-s` isn't an option

Comment: Just as a reminder, for me and others who work with Zabbix: this example is EXTREMELY USEFUL, when it comes to commands that require sudo permissions. Example: if you provide access to `nginx -t` to `zabbix` user via sudoers, and want to test the command `sudo /usr/sbin/nginx -t`. You can run `su -s /bin/bash -c 'sudo /usr/sbin/nginx -t' zabbix`, even when `zabbix` user has `nologin` as shell.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this with `sudo -u` if you have it installed:

```
# whoami
root
# sudo -u apache whoami
apache
# getent passwd apache
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/sbin/nologin
```

Comment: How do you pass parameters to `sudo -u apache whoami`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Any parameters after the command will be passed along. You can think of it like "sudo [-u apache] [whoami <param1> <param2>]".

Comment: I think using `sudo -u` is probably not a good idea for running commands as a nologin user, because it exposes the `SUDO_USER` in the environment who is the real one invokes the command. Maybe I am just overthinking it.

Answer (score 8):

By providing the script as the argument to execute to /bin/sh:

```
su -s "/bin/sh /your/script/location" username
```

Answer (score 2):

just realized :

su -s "/bin/bash" -c "/bin/touch /tmp/testuser" testuser

maybe there is a better way ?!

Answer (score 2):

actually, the best way to do this is via **runuser**

see the man page for details

this tool is used to deal with the situation as the developer said in his bolg

#### Whenever an service is running as root and wants to change UID using the shell it should use runuser.

http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/55588.html

i've post this answer in many palaces, forgive me if you find this annoying

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers to prevent link rot. Instead, add the most relevant information from the link to your answer or alternatively, post the link as a comment instead of an answer. See this http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer help center article for further information.

Comment: @FedericoGalli the most relevant information is already added, there is no need to copy and paste the usage, the man page provides enough information

Answer (score -1):

Use sudo -u to specify the user. Also use the -i flag to set environment variables of the target user too.

```
sudo -i -u user command
```

Comment: this gives `This account is currently not available.`

Answer (score -1):

All you need is `sudo`:

`sudo -u <user> -g <group> -- <command>`

Answer (score -2):

Use su command with shell -s and -c command. As shown below

```
 su  exec -l -c '/bin/bash /etc/update_conf.sh' -s /bin/bash
```

Comment: That's exactly the solution from the highest rated answer.